# Running "git status" against a repository located elsewhere in the system

Tags: windows, linux, git, shell

I know that I can do this:

```
git --git-dir="Z:/www/proj/web/test/sample-repo-cloned/.git" status
```

However, the problem is that the command is run from `proj` folder, which means that all files that are located before `sample-repo-cloned` will also be taken into account.

Is there a way to run this command under the scope of `sample-repo-cloned` folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to specify the working tree as well as the git directory:

```
--work-tree
```

Ie:

```
git --work-tree="Z:/www/proj/web/test/sample-repo-cloned/" --git-dir="Z:/www/proj/web/test/sample-repo-cloned/.git"  status
```

The result should be local to the working tree root directory.

Comment: Just a note that not all commands are consistent with adhering to these git level options. Stash is one that comes to mind. It doesn't seem to work or at least in certain cases perhaps with relative paths...

Comment: Cheers :) .. code around those commands takes a different path. Not as easy to fix as I thought. Maybe this weekend...

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with `(cd Z:/www/proj/web/test/sample-repo-cloned ; git status)` ??