# RTC to Git Migration using rtc2git - https://github.com/WtfJoke/rtc2git

Tags: git, python-2.7, python-3.x, rtc

I need to migrate the source code from RTC SCM to Git along with the history. I have seen a post put in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23928927/how-to-migrate-from-rtc-jazz-to-git)  and tried downloading it from GitHub and I get compilation error when I execute the "migration.py" script.
 First I tried to Insatll Python version 3 and I get an error saying "ImportError: cannot import name check_output" , when I checked the a resolution for this they say you need to install Python version 2.7

Now when I have Python 2.7 I get a new error saying "ImportError: no module named configparser"

If I could get this "rtc2git" script working it would be great !

Any help is very much appreciated !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python 3.3.5 installation fixed this issue for me.
Downloaded from - https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-335/